# Classes for translation of text (e.g. en -> de)

Tags: c#, asp.net, translation

HI guys,
I was wondering if there is any microsoft class which converts a language like english into german, french etc.
I want to convert some data into specific language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a class built into .NET base class library, no, there's not one as of .NET 4.0 beta 1 and I don't expect something like that included in the framework itself. Microsoft provides a Web service, [Bing translator](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/Tools/) that you can use in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the ambiguous nature of [human] language, such a class is not possible to implement in a well-defined manner, and as such will never be part of the .NET Framework. However, there are third party tools and services that provide translation services. If you want real results worthy of a multilingual product release, the ***only*** option is having a human translator do the translation, and then include the result in your distributed program.